# Loopback: Connect with xampp server using Windows

Tags: sockets, xampp, loopbackjs

I am trying to connect to my xampp server but it is not being connected.
Here is my datasources.json

```
{
    "db": {
        "name": "db",
        "connector": "memory"
    }
    "test": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 3306,
        "database": "test",
        "name": "test",
        "debug": false,
        "connector": "mysql",
        "socketPath" : "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini"
    }
}
```

I do not know that my socket path is having an issue.

Error:

```
Error:connect ENOTSOCK C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config file socketpath should be given socket file that is .sock extension commonly 
C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: I have also tried the path. The error is : Error:connect ENONET

Answer (score 0):

> You are not gaving the password and username of mysql database

```
  "test": {
     "host": "127.0.0.1",
     "port": 3306,
     "database": "mysqltest",
      "password": "",              ///password
      "name": "test",
       "connector": "mysql",
      "user": "root"               ///username 
    }
```